# Windows goes nutty when I use my php script to open a .exe file

Tags: c#, php, windows

I have been playing around with using a php script to open a C# application.  Now when I run the script a window pops up saying, "A program running on this computer is trying to display a message".  I click on view message and a message pop up saying the program will display below if it need attention, and below that a return to windows button.  Does anyone know what is going on and how I can work around it?

Here is my php script

```
<?php

exec('C:\\nothing.exe');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

one approach:

WScript.Shell object gives you a number of parameters depending on how you want it to run

```
$WshShell = new COM("WScript.Shell");
$oExec = $WshShell->Run("C:\\nothing.exe", 0, false);
```

bWaitOnReturn
"If set to false (the default), the Run method returns immediately after starting the program, automatically returning 0 (not to be interpreted as an error code)."

Comment: When I echo $oExec I get a zero

Comment: Sorry, so why am I getting a zero?  The file is there and the path is fine.